# Rest extension API to upload a file in marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I would like to create a custom endpoint to upload files, can I use the generic Rest API stubs and use the POST method to get the file content.. I see in the documentation

> In MarkLogic 8, POST methods in a single-statement transaction are executed in query mode

what does that mean ? can I just do the following,

```
declare function repo:post($context as map:map, $params  as map:map,$input   as document-node()*) as document-node()*
{
   let $filename := xdmp:get-request-field-filename("upload")
   let $contentType := xdmp:get-request-field-content-type("upload")
......
};
```

will this take "multipart/form-data;" ?? Are there any examples that I can look ? The above way does not seem to be working for me

I also tried (and love the annotations) using RXQ (https://github.com/xquery/rxq),  but fails for multipart/form-data ..

Any pointers on how to approach will be really helpful..

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: Can you share the essential bits of your form?

Comment: When I do use ML8 out of the box URL rewriter /MarkLogic/rest-api/rewriter.xml) it all works fine.. I was using the custom URL rewriter by "rxq" as it supports annotations so I don;t need to create a separate xqy for each endpoint.. but looks like rxq fails in ML8..

Comment: Yes, the new declarative rewriter of ML8 makes it more difficult to extend the built-in one..

Comment: Please file a ticket for this specifically on that github project..

Comment: I field the ticket with that project.. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to write a single document, consider using the built-in REST endpoint:

http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/v1/documents

If you want to execute some custom logic at the same time a document is written, one simple approach is to specify a transform that performs the side-effect action and simply passes through the document unchanged:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/transforms

If your custom logic must handle the write, consider using the PUT method:

http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/v1/resources/%5Bname%5D

When writing a single document, you specify the mime type that identifies the document format.  When writing a batch of documents, you should package the batch as a multipart/mixed payload in which each part specifies the mime type for the document format.

When using a REST extension, you don't need to interact with HTTP. The REST API does that for you, getting the document and passing it to your function. You just write a function that has the expected signature:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_75991

And install the library module with the function:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_59112

Hoping that helps,